# I'm just trying to use mediasoup npm but don't know how to record streams / conversations from mediasoup npm

Tags: node.js, npm, webrtc, mediasoup

I'm just building a demo webrtc app with [mediasoup](https://github.com/versatica/mediasoup) npm. I am just trying to record the conversation for recording feature. but there is no docs related to this feature in mediasoup readme.

Is there any way to accomplish this using this npm or any other alternatives that makes building feature rich webrtc application using nodejs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the project with mediasoup recording implemented [mediasoup3-record-demo](https://github.com/ethand91/mediasoup3-record-demo)

Comment: Thanks for the quick demo. Is there any article that explains the steps to do this ?

Comment: you can check the documentation https://mediasoup.org/documentation/v3/

Answer (score 0):

you can record media stream on mediasoup using **ffmpeg** or **gstreamer** where these two are basically starting process of consuming media stream and write it into a file, with the help of node streams,

but briefly you must treat the processes started by ffmpeg or gstreamer as consumers, by means of starting media soup transport and consumer to pipe stream to the above mentioned processes,

mind you, the transport created for this purpose needs to be [PlainRtpTranspor](https://mediasoup.org/documentation/v3/mediasoup/api/#PlainTransport)

[this mediasoup3-record-demo example mentioned it all](https://github.com/ethand91/mediasoup3-record-demo)